# How to update time by javascript code is givnen

Tags: javascript

```
var time = new Date();
var hour = time.getHours();
var min = time.getMinutes();
var sec = time.getSeconds();

function myTime() {
  if (hour < 12) {
    sort = "AM";
  } else {
    sort = "PM";
  }
  if (min < 10) {
    min = "0" + min;
  }
  if (sec < 10) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }

  document.write("Current time is: " + "<b>" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + sort + "</b>");
}
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  myTime()
}, 1000);
```

I write this code but this not run properly.how can I update seconds automatically as well as minutes hours? I use interval functions for update time but it does not update time. help me

Comment: You have added time calculation outside the function. Add it inside the function so that it takes the current time

Comment: this is taking current time but issue /problem is that SETINTERVAL function is repeating the time string again and again.i want just to update time instead of string repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put all variables inside function, so whenever function call, get the latest value.

Also you can use `innerHTML` if you dont want to rewrite all string every time.

```js
function myTime(){

    var time=new Date();
    var hour=time.getHours();
    var min=time.getMinutes();
    var sec=time.getSeconds();

    if(hour<12){
        sort="AM";
    }
    else{
        sort="PM";
    }
    if(min<10){
        min="0"+min;
    }
    if(sec<10){
        sec="0"+sec;
    }

//document.write("Current time is: "+"<b>"+hour+":"+min+":"+sec+" "+sort+"</b>");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Current time is: "+"<b>"+hour+":"+min+":"+sec+" "+sort+"</b>";
    }
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTime()},1000);
```

```html
<span id="demo"> </span>
```

Comment: Time string is repeating when setinterval is working but I want just update time, not time string repeat again and again.

Comment: @HanzalahAnees See my updated answer, use on `span` or any tag you want, and use `innerHTML`  to update time

Comment: in this way, is correct but this is the second way. maybe my code is wrong. ok Thank you very much for the effort.